# RestKit 0.2: flattening the hierarchy in JSON

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

Maybe there's a similar question here, but I could not find it. So I have the RestKit 0.2pre4 and want to map such JSON ...

```
{
    "location": {
        "position": {
            "latitude": 53.9675028,
            "longitude": 10.1795594
        }
    },
    "id": "da3224f2-5919-42f2-9dd8-9171088f4ad7",
    "name": "Something even more beautiful",
}
```

... to such an object:

```
@interface FavoritePlace : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * placeId;
@property (assign, nonatomic) double latitude;
@property (assign, nonatomic) double longitude;

@end
```

As you can see, the point is that I don't want to create a relationship and store "Location" object in database separately - it just doesn't make sense. Therefore I want to assign those nested things (location.position.latitude and location.position.longitude) to particular properties of object itself. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I did a wild ass guess and it worked! Here's the mapping which does the trick:

```
[placeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id": @"placeId",
     @"name": @"name",
     @"location.position.latitude": @"latitude",
     @"location.position.longitude": @"longitude"     
     }];
```

Have not found this in documentation, but maybe it's just me... Anyway, if something logical, but undocumented, works, then framework should be good. :) RestKit FTW!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string containig the json string to nsdata with

```
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then, you will be able to parse de json data with the iOS API with

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error] : nil;
```

Now, examine the generated NSDictionary (with NSlog for example), fill your 'FavoritePlace' object and persist it.

Hope helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd prefer to stay inside the RestKit realms, if possible. Starting fiddling around with raw JSON would ruin the whole purpose of using the RestKit, imho...

Comment: Oki, in that cause I can not help you xD. Good Luck!

Comment: Why don't you look into the documentation of your 3rd party framework? If the functionality and documentation are not satisfactory, abandon it.